# How to output the log in restassured, I want to show the log in my report. not in console windows

Tags: logging, rest-assured

```
  given().
            log().
            ifValidationFails().
            contentType(RestConfigKeys.KEY_REST_CONTENT_TYPE).
            request().
            body(jsonObject.toString()).
            when().
            post(resource).
            then().
            log().
            ifValidationFails().
            statusCode(201);
```

using restassured to verify rest uri and the log showed in console window as below:

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    http://10.89.121.163/PSCLNP/rest/1/roles
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
            Content-Type=application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json; 
charset=ISO-8859-1
Cookies:        <none>
Body:
{
"Role": "test001",
"Description": "test001",
"ValidFromDate": "2016-08-28",
"ValidToDate": "4712-12-31"
}
```

I want to show above log into my report, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `System.out` is used as print stream. If you want your log to be presented in report you need to add proper logging to your tests or create additional REST Assured logging filter which will send logs to your reporting system.